# SVN Blame for Vim

Tags: svn, vim

Is there any pluggin for vim which can show 'svn blame' output in a vertical split showing  line by line author and revision number ( like 'Gblame' in vim-fugitive for git).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [vcscommand.vim - CVS/SVN/SVK/git/hg/bzr integration plugin](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=90) has a `:VCSAnnotate` command that shows the annotations either prepended to a copy of the current buffer, or (with `!`) in a vertical split that moves with the original buffer.